# Flicker on jQuery fadeIn due to caching

Tags: jquery, fadein, flicker, waitforimages

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div').hide();
    $('#div').waitForImages(function() {
        $('#div').fadeIn();
    });
})
```

This works perfectly when the user first comes to the site. On refresh, however, there is lots of flickering due to caching. I've tried moving the `$('#div').hide();` to several different places throughout the document but the result is the same. I've also tried `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).load()` but it didn't help. Of course, if I set `display: none` in the CSS, then there is no flicker, but this means the site is broken for non-JavaScript users. I've also tried setting the CSS via JavaScript (i.e. `$(#div).css({'display':'none'});` but this didn't work. There must be a way!

Comment: check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3DfGP/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `display: none` for the images. I feel that's only way out. Regarding the site being broken for other users, put a link to a stylesheet inside a `<noscript>` tag that corrects the situation if no JS support is deteccted.

Comment: Good call on the <noscript> tag.

Answer (score 1):

try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3DfGP/)

```
$('body').waitForImages(

function() {
    $('body').append('<p>Images loaded.</p>');
}, function(loaded, total) {
    $(this).css({
        border: '1px solid #ccc'
    });
    $('span').html(parseInt(loaded / total * 100) + '% loaded.');
});
```

Comment: You may want to mention that this requires a plugin.